# What's it called when a manager changes narrative to employees in the wrong?

Tags: manager, employer-relations, terminology

What's it called when a manager changes an employee issue with the organisation into the employee doing something wrong?

Example 1: Consider this as an example: employee reports a problem (say some computer system isn't working). Manager instead of addressing issue reported says to the reporting employee "you didn't use the correct system for reporting the error".

Example 2 (added later): employee reports concerns about system x not working. Manager asks as only follow up were you using system y at the time? System x and y are unrelated but there is a policy that is widely ignored that system y must be used at all times.

Don't want to get into why this is bad practice just want to know what this type of management technique is called.

Edit 2: the goal of the manager appears to be turn the reported problem around onto employees. That way they don't follow up with manager and organisation won't be forced to fix problems reported.

Edit 3: these are all hypothetical examples. And are not actually affecting me personally.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it less about the example.

Comment: Yes manager agrees the system isn't working as it should.

Comment: I think it's possible that gaslighting is the correct term. But I'm not sure.

Comment: A technique is something that achieves some sort of purpose. You should probably include what you are imagining is being achieved by the manager so we can get a better idea about what's going on.

Comment: Thankyou. I have made a second edit.

Comment: What you describe is not gaslighting. It could be deflection if your assumption about the manager's motives are correct, but as others have pointed out, that is not substantiated by your examples.

Comment: Some googling says corporate deflection is like the term I'm looking for. @Corey if you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: As I said, that term does not describe those examples, hypothetical or not. It is not "deflection" to insist that the correct reporting mechanism is used. You can write and accept your own answer.

Comment: My first thought on that was, what if the manager simply wants to have the correct tool used so that the report goes to where it's processed best and fastest? Who doesn't know situations when one would like to respond to someone "I am not responsible, please tell X about that". In this case the best term for that would be "efficient working" :-) Do you exclude this possibility for a particular reason?

Comment: I don't think your examples enhance the question as intended. In the first example, I think it is ok when a manager points out you should go through correct channels or use correct system for reporting problems. This is often done for good reason such as efficiency, having a history and searchable database etc. I believe what you are trying to ask here is about the manager turning the tables on the employee to make it look like the employee is at fault. OR the manager is distracting from the problem. This is not made clear (enough) in the problem description, I think.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a technique, it just normal practice to ensure employees are aware of and follow correct reporting procedures. You're supposed to learn from it and re-report the problem correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Example 1:  It is normal for company to have a standard procedure for reporting.  So just by this, it is not making your point that manager is turning against employee.

Example  2:  Well if you are not supposed to use X, why bother about whether it is working or not? It could be an archived and not in use system and you are indeed supposed to use Y. Again, I do not see a big concern with your boss's response here.

Comment: I understood that OP was supposed to be using X, and also Y at the same time, but was only using X, which wasn't working properly for reasons that (OP thinks) are completely unrelated to the use of Y.